# Time taken by first curl call is large

Tags: curl

I have curl on my ubuntu AWS instance. I am using it to calculate performance numbers of my API like this

```
curl -w %{time_total} https://myurl/v1.0/vernumber
```

Here is the timing I am getting

60 ms
20 ms
21 ms 
19 ms

As you can see first call is taking much more time as compared to further same request. Question is why the subsequent calls take less time and how to prevent that.

Is it caching the SSL connection , if yes how to prevent curl from caching the SSL connection.

Comment: Is the system under load as you start this, or are you warming up the application with your first call which is why it's taking a bit longer?

Comment: Ok what is meant by warming up here?? By application you mean at server side.

Comment: system is not under load when I start this.

Comment: Yes, if you've not requested any resources from the server it may well have a few start-up processes it needs to do. Alternatively if this is a new curl session there could be an initial DNS or routing delay as your request is serviced by network infrastructure.